# Использование атрибута PACK_KEYS

Tags: атрибуты, mysql, sql

Привет. Кто-то может подсказать рекомендации когда использовать данный атрибут? 
 Где он негативно влияет и где позитивно?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

pack_keys - флаг, принимающий значение 0 (выключено) или 1 (включено). Во включённом состоянии происходит сжатие текстовых (CHAR и VARCHAR) и числовых индексов. Это приводит к замедлению операциям вставки, удаления и обновления данных, но увеличивает скорость их извлечения.

Если данные очень редко вставляются, но часто извлекаются - к примеру забиваем какойнить справочник состояний заказов - понятно что его впринципе 1 раз забили и юзают (1-2 раза ченит добавится возможно) - тогда можно юзать. Если имеем дело с самими заказами - то тут часто добавление идет - тут лучше не юзать